# OData endpoint on node.js is throwing error

Tags: node.js, odata

I have followed instructions in link-http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-set-up-a-nodejs-odata-endpoint-with-odata-server and I am able to access the end point with URL- localhost:52999/todo/.When I try to access todo collection with URL-localhost:52999/todo/Todos, it is throwing following error.Could anyone please help.I am expecting blank page as the collection has zero elements

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'providerConfiguration' of undefined
   at JSObjectAdapter.$data.Class.define.processRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\jaydata\lib\JayService\JSObjectAdapter.js:79:147)
   at JSObjectAdapter.$data.Class.define.handleRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\jaydata\lib\JayService\JSObjectAdapter.js:170:26)
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\jaydata\lib\JayService\JayService.js:61:21
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\odata-server\index.js:121:36
   at Domain.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\odata-server\index.js:81:13)
   at Domain.run (domain.js:197:16)
   at errorFn (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\odata-server\index.js:80:14)
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\odata-server\index.js:118:29
   at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\jaydata\lib\JayService\OData\Helpers.js:144:17
   at simpleBodyFn (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\odata-server\index.js:63:56)
```

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589242/odata-service-using-nodejs-and-jaydata/32193177#32193177